# angular2 - adding 'pattern' for form builder

Tags: regex, validation, angular

I have a pattern for a form builder and I have this:

```
 this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'postalCode': ['', Validators.pattern('/[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z] [0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]/i')]
    });
```

I have a **ValidationService** which I've added a function "getValidatorErrorMessage".

```
static getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
    let config = {
        'pattern': 'invalid  pattern'
    };

    return config[validatorName];
}
```

My template has:

```
  <div>
        <label for="postalCode">Postal code (A1A 2J3)</label>
        <input formControlName="postalCode" id="postalCode" />
        <control-messages [control]="userForm.controls.postalCode"></control-messages>
    </div>
```

But for some odd reason, the validation messages arent displaying if I dont follow the regex code.

You can view the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiHLvY48Qfj5UzdzevpS?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you set a condition in your `ControlMessagesComponent` that input field has to be `touched` in order for error message to be displayed:

```
get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) &&
          this.control.touched) { // this line
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you remove `this.control.touched`, validation will be performed as you type. But this also will result in `required` messages being displayed right away. Combination I prefer most is to display error message in two cases: when user clicks on input field and then clicks somewhere else or when user starts typing which can be achieved with following condition:

```
if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) &&
    this.control.dirty ||
    this.control.touched)
```